# Why does setTimeout in Angular & dramatically increase runtime performance?

Tags: angular

This is gonna sound a bit abstract, but I'm really curious as to what might be possible cause of this behavior.

Setup:

> Angular 9.1.0
>   All components use OnPush detection strategy

I have component (quite UI heavy with flex layout) which is initialized in *ngFor about 10 times on a page. This component has single number Input property from which it generates layout.

When I use:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (this.id) {
      this.initComponent(this.id); // this triggers component to be rendered
   }
}
```

it takes about 5-7 seconds to render.

If I use:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (this.itemId) {
          setTimeout(() => {
           this.initComponent(this.itemId ?? 0);
    }, 1);
  }
}
```

it takes under 1 second to render everything. I'm looking for **ideas** of what might be causing such behavior so that I can improve my code or understand the flaw in my current code.

Comment: that's interesting and weird at the same time, could you please provide a reproduction link?

Comment: it could be that your initComponent is depending on other code that takes 5-7 sec, please provide more information about that function.

Comment: yeah, it is. I suspect something is blocking the main thread and causing those components to be rendered in sequence, whereas if I use setTimeout it renders them at the same time independently. I just cant seem to figure why. I would have to hame some more time to reproduce this, we have quite complex enterprise app.

Comment: Perhaps post this or search for it on the angular github page? They are very responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular runs as a single thread application. So when you try to render the UI it has to wait for the Javascript engine to finish its processing to be rendered.

`setTimeout()` is scheduled in native code. So essentially what happens is that the Javascript engine exits to native code, native code (`setTimeout()`) renders the UI and then exits to go back to the Javascript engine where it can continue processing.

Hence, putting your UI code in `setTimeout()` produces that result.